# Is there a conceivable frequentist counter to the Bayesian calculation of life in other planets?

Tags: probability, bayesian, frequentist

[This paper](http://www.pnas.org/content/109/2/395.abstract) in the *Proceedings of the Natural Academy of Sciences of the United States of America* attempts to give a Bayesian probability of life outside planet Earth.

Their approach is based on a priori estimations of a rate parameter, $\lambda$ (*probability of abiogenesis per unit of time*), as part of a Poisson distribution that would give us the probability of life arising during the right period of the geological time in a "Goldilocks" planet suitable for life nurturing. They claim to use an un-informative $prior$ for this rate parameter, which would be somewhat guessed by the early development of life in the life of planet Earth.

The data or $likelihood$ seems to be extracted from the estimate of the number of Earth-like exoplanets, and the time constraints for the development of life.

The results are quite disparate with distributions ranging the gamut, but in some cases denoting pessimism as to life elsewhere in the galaxy.

The scope of the results is so broad that it is difficult to take issue with the paper, which I am positive was peer-reviewed and prepared with maximum care and expertise.

But it would be interesting to know whether this question could be treated from a frequentist (orthodox) approach.

From the first comment I got, it seems like we do have an acknowledgement of the prominence of our prior on the posterior, given the lack of data or evidence. It would be a very different scenario if a [drop captured from an Enceladus gushing geyser](http://www.techinsider.io/cassini-sampling-enceladus-ocean-water-2015-10) showed evidence of a bacterium.

But can we conclude that this is a really stimulating "guessing game" in the paper that couldn't be a frequentist parallel given the absence of data?

Comment: From the abstract: "We find that, given only this very limited empirical information, the choice of Bayesian prior...has a dominant influence on the computed posterior probability."

Comment: I had noticed that part. Are you implying that in fact only a Bayesian approach can work in this case?

Comment: If there is a likelihood function on $\lambda$, a frequentist estimator of $\lambda$ can certainly be derived, along with a confidence interval.

Comment: Interesting... I was a bit confused about whether the prior was the probability of $\lambda$, or the actual Poisson distribution estimating the probability of life occurring from one second to the next - but in any event we were discussing the *prior*. Now, you are mentioning the likelihood... we are moving leftward in the Bayes equation... I have to think hard to understand what you have in mind...